# Special function $Z_r(x)$ in Plasma physics.

Tags: physics, special-functions

A friend of mine  is reading [this article](https://arxiv-export3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/2110.01433) (eq.2,pg-5) about **Plasma Physics**  and trying to find what the s function $Z_r(x)$ is. . He's been trying to find out for half an hour. I'm typing this question on his behalf.

In plasma physics, one common special function is $Z(x)$, called the plasma dispersion function, but this article uses $Z_r(x)$, i.e., with the subscript $r$. It's surely not the plasma dispersion function, because $Z_r(x)$ is real (as there are no complex numbers involved in the article) while the plasma dispersion function is a complex function. The function $Z_r(x)$ appears in the article as a result of 3D integration of some exponents and logarithms and then making a Taylor expansion. The article author seems to assume it's a commonly known function as he doesn't define it anywhere in his article.

---

What is the special function $Z_r(x)$? What is its name, and how is this function defined?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I included the link to the full text of the article.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I've just added an update to include more details

Comment: I tried to clean up the question a bit. Hope you find the answer for your friend :). If you don't get an answer here you can also try r/askPhysics or the mathematics help subreddit

Comment: Have a look at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234928947_Kinetic_theory_of_solitary_waves_on_coasting_beams_in_synchrotrons  at equation $(14)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, this has resolved the issue :) It turns out that this is the real part of the plasma dispersion function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the answer thanks to the hint by @ClaudeLeibovic in the comments below the original post. The hint was to look at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234928947_Kinetic_theory_of_solitary_waves_on_coasting_beams_in_synchrotrons

And that article defines $Z_r(x)$. It's the real part of the plasma dispersion function $Z(x)$ mentioned in my original post.